# ADFS custom claim rule: fails for one group, works for two or more

Tags: adfs

I've inherited an ADFS set up with a couple of custom claim rules that assigns SAML roles based on membership in groups that are named with a specific prefix.

The first retrieves all the groups and populates roles:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", 
   Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => add(
    store = "Active Directory", 
    types = ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"), 
    query = ";tokenGroups;{0}", 
    param = c.Value);
```

The second filters that list to only the ones with the required prefix:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", 
   Value =~ "(?i)^prefix.*"]
   => issue(claim = c);
```

However, this doesn't work if the user belongs to only one of the prefixed groups, with no roles being returned. If they're added to a second group with the same prefix, then both return.

I'm not overly familiar with the claim rules DSL but this seems to be identical to examples I've seen. Is there a way to have it return a list of roles if only one matching group is found?

Comment: Is there another rule that populates role?

Comment: @nzpcmad my bad, I've updated the question to include it, thanks.